# How to build the latest Version of WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to test if the newest head/trunk/master version of WSO2 Identity Server.

I found a version on gitlab (https://github.com/wso2/platform) an a version SVN (https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/)

What is the preferred way to build the latest version of WSO2 Identity Server.

kindly regards Philipp

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Identity Server is 5.0.0. Using [this](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/) release matrix, you can find the `branch`, `chunk` and `patch` that identity server 5.0.0 has been released.  It is `Turing` branch , `chunk 11` and kernal patch `0008`.  You can find chuck 11 from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/product-releases/chunk-11/) and kernel patch from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0008/)

However if you need to build the current version.  Then i am not sure the exact chunk and patch as it is not release. However it must be the highest chunk value and patch value that are available in same location that i have shared for 11 and 0008

Still Identity Server is not used the github to release it.